# order by coma separated list without quotes

Tags: php, mysql

need to order by field, using a coma separated list

```
$sql = "select cat from steps group by cat order by field (cat, " . $str . ")";
```

the above works only if `$str = 'lorem','ipsum','dolor'`

but my `$str` is `lorem,ipsum,dolor` i.e. without quotes

how to get the `$str` with quotes or force to execute `sql` without quotes?

Comment: You need the quotes. Fix how you create `$str`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `FIELD()` you can use [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
select cat from steps group by cat order by find_in_set(cat, '" . $str . "')
```

Comment: Quotes are needed around `lorem,ipsum,dolor`, not for every item in the list.

Comment: @spencer7593 although I'm not an expert in php, I think that the double quotes around . $str . serve this purpose, or not?

Comment: spencer is correct.  The double-quotes are _closing_ the string (and then re-opening).  They are not part of the SQL statement.  That's what adding the single-quotes is for.

Answer (score 3):

You need the quotes, otherwise MySQL thinks they're column names, not literal strings.

You can add them with code like this:

```
$exp = explode(',', $str);
foreach ($exp as &$item) {
    $item = "'$item'";
}
$str = implode(',', $exp);
```